# radwindow does not show in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dotnetnuke, radwindow, registerstartupscript

I am new in dotnetnuke module development.

Settings: dotnetnuke 7 + christoc module, telerik ajax ui conrols: Q2 release 2. I have registered a usercontrol Patientupdate.ascx in DNN. Inside it I have several controls i.e. a radgrid (ResultaatGrid)  and a radwindow, also as a user control (but not registered in DNN)  named COVUserControl. The radwindow is called inside a radgrid in formedit mode when a button is click.

a snippet of the code for the radwindow(inside the patientupdate.ascx)

In the radwindow I have put the usercontrol (COVUserControl) and inside the user control I have defined a radgrid.

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="COVWindow" Title="Editing record" Width="270"
        Height="540" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" Behaviors="Resize, Minimize, Close, Pin, Maximize, Move"
        Left="610" EnableShadow="true" runat="server" OnClientClose="refreshGrid" Modal="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <COVUC:COVUserControl runat="server" ID="COVUCID"/>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

In the edit template I have a button named  (in the patientupdate.ascx)  and in the code behind of the patientupdate.ascx.cs

in the ResultaatGrid_Itemcommand  I have the following code:

```
     protected void ResultaatGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "COV")
        {
            GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            string pCperID = editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("cpersoon_id").ToString();
            COVWindow.Width = 500;
            COVWindow.Height = 250;
            COVUserControl COVUC1 = COVWindow.ContentContainer.FindControl("COVUCID") as COVUserControl;
            COVUC1.cPersoonID = pCperID;
            RadGrid COVGrid = COVUC1.FindControl("COVGrid") as RadGrid;
            string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + COVWindow.ClientID + "\").show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", script, true);
            COVGrid.Rebind();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the radwindow does not pop-up.  (I have check the pop-up in host -> extension-> and check allow pop-ups for the module).

When debugging (attach) I see Covgrid.rebind is fired because it fires the radgrid need datasource of the grid inside the COVUserControl.

The same code works, the radwindow pop-up, when NOT a dotnetnuke module. (just plain patientupdate.aspx).

I think that the following code lines does not fire:

```
string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + COVWindow.ClientID + "\").show();     
Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going the same route as you with the radwindow in DNN and the short answer is don't use `Sys.Application.add_load` when in DNN, it doesn't like it at all. Has to do with the component is not loaded via Sys.Application.add_init().
Go with `pageLoad()` instead.

Comment: I try the follwing code but with NO success :-(
function GetCOVWindow() {
 var wnd = $find("<%=COVWindow.ClientID %>");
 wnd.open();
 } 
In code behind:
string script = "$(document).ready(function() { GetCOVWindow();});";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", script, true);

Comment: $find is a shortcut to the findComponent method of the Sys.Application class which defined by the Microsoft AJAX Library, so it to find a component not html DOM, which might not be ready yet

Comment: My suggestion is to make this work first in the ascx, make some button and try to open the radwindow onclientclick, if it works move it to code-behind.

Comment: Events before Sys.Application.Load cannot guarantee you will have the Sys.Component objects created by MS AJAX.

Comment: @rdmptn, that what I said regarding using $find on document.ready, it should be used on pageLoad. Why is the downgrade of the answer?

Comment: I probably misread something late last night. I would suggest editing your posts instead of adding subsequent comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

I have had some issues when registering scripts from user controls or custom controls. Registering them through the Page object has not failed me so far.